# Vue.js - Add delete button on hover and delete it on button press

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the below data coming from another server which is not in my control and when displaying it in the browser I have to provide a solution to

1) Show delete button for the class `childElement` on hover

2) Click on delete button and delete that `childElement` div

Is there any way I can do it using CSS/JS or Vuejs ( Dynamically adding Delete button on hover and delete the element on button click) ? Thank You

```css
.childElement {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:#f3f3f3;
margin-top:10px;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="videos">
<div class="childElement">
first div
</div>
<div class="childElement">
second div
</div>
<div class="childElement">
third div
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what went wrong with GenericUser answer?

Comment: It is the solution I am looking for . There is nothing wrong with his answer

Comment: i put his script  inside mounted hook of Vue instance and i removed the logic that i did before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work basically boils down to some script that will find all the elements and auto append elements with listeners.

```js
const childElements = document.querySelectorAll('.childElement');
childElements.forEach(childElement => {
  // create button for each childElement
  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  deleteButton.setAttribute('hidden', '');
  deleteButton.innerText = "Click to delete";
  // append button to the childElement
  childElement.appendChild(deleteButton);

  // add event listeners
  childElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', event => {
    deleteButton.removeAttribute('hidden');
  });

  childElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', event => {
    deleteButton.setAttribute('hidden', '');
  });

  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
    childElement.setAttribute('hidden', '');
  });
});
```

```css
.childElement {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="videos">
  <div class="childElement">
    first div
  </div>
  <div class="childElement">
    second div
  </div>
  <div class="childElement">
    third div
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an array to your data object called `childDivs` and which item inside that array contains a boolean `showBtn` intilially its value is `false` and the text to be shown inside the div element

UPDATE :

the above described logic could be useful when you could control the data in front-end, but according to the OP's use case, we could add the script given by @GenericUser inside the mounted hook.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      childDivs: [{
          text: 'First',
          showBtn: false
        },
        {
          text: 'Second',
          showBtn: false
        },
        {
          text: 'Third',
          showBtn: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    remove(i) {
      this.childDivs.splice(i, 1)

    }
  },

  mounted() {
    const childElements = document.querySelectorAll('.childElement');
    childElements.forEach(childElement => {
      const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
      deleteButton.setAttribute('hidden', '');
      deleteButton.innerText = "delete";
      deleteButton.classList.add("btn")
      deleteButton.classList.add("btn-danger")
      childElement.appendChild(deleteButton);
      childElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', event => {
        deleteButton.removeAttribute('hidden');
      });
      childElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', event => {
        deleteButton.setAttribute('hidden', '');
      });

      deleteButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
        childElement.setAttribute('hidden', '');
      });
    });
  }

})
```

```css
.childElement {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div id="app" data-app>

  <div id="videos">
    <div class="childElement">
      first div
    </div>
    <div class="childElement">
      second div
    </div>
    <div class="childElement">
      third div
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank You , but the data I am getting from the external server has the structure that I mentioned , so I can not split them into Child data object and in for loop.

Comment: could you show how you're getting that? and how do you want to delete items?

Comment: This is what  I am getting from server and videos can have any number of childElements   <div id="videos">
  <div class="childElement">
    first div
  </div>
  <div class="childElement">
    second div
  </div>
  <div class="childElement">
    third div
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Please see the solution provided by GenericUser and you will understand what I am talking

Comment: sorry i misunderstood you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code 
   also use jquery to you project 
   here like this

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="videos">
<div class="childElement" id="divOne" >
<div id="delete">X</div>
first div
</div>
<div class="childElement">
second div
</div>
<div class="childElement">
third div
</div>
</div>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#divOne").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
    }, function(){
    $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
  });

  $("#delelte").on("click",()=>{
      $("#divOne").children().remove();
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: sorry I am not using JQUERY here . only CSS/JavaScript/VUEJS

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one with jQuery:

```js
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.childElement', function(e){
  
    $(this).append('<div class="remove">remove it</div>');
  
    $('.childElement').on('mouseleave', function(){
      $('.remove').remove();
    });
  
    $('body').on('click', '.remove', function(e){
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });

});
```

```css
.childElement {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:#f3f3f3;
margin-top:10px;
padding:10px;
}

.remove {
 position:absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 background: #000;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="videos">
<div class="childElement">
first div
</div>
<div class="childElement">
second div
</div>
<div class="childElement">
third div
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry I am not using JQUERY here . only CSS/JavaScript/VUEJS

Comment: @Bujji please add more info next time ( like **ONLY** native js ) to avoid situations like this, because **jQuery** IS A **JavaScript** library

Comment: I am sorry . Thank you and I will make sure